# Table position text css

Tags: html, css, text, html-table, position

I want to have my text on the top-left in the 3rd cell.

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/24nd5/

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 15%;">
        lol lol lol lol lol
        lol lol lol lol lol
        lol lol lol lol lol
        lol lol lol lol lol
    </td>
    <td style="width: 3%;">

    </td>
    <td style="">
        Name
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: position: absolute;
width: 78%;
border: 0;
Give this style to <td>
http://jsfiddle.net/24nd5/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it more dynamic you can add:

```
table tr td:last-child  { vertical-align:top; }
```

or

```
table tr td:nth-child(3) { vertical-align:top; }
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/24nd5/9/)

Now if you add more rows each last cell  (or third depends on which code you use from the above) wil have the text in the left top corner

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/24nd5/10/)

Answer (score 3):

please add this inline CSS in your last `<td>`

```
vertical-align:top;
```

Here is the updated Demo link.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/24nd5/1/)

Comment: Hi Zak, you should checked the green mark, so other people know what answer is more accurate. otherwise more confusing for user who are looking for same kind of answer.

Comment: and if you want to apply this only for 3rd cell, you can use pseudo-selector `:last-child`

Answer (score 2):

This is easy, just add ***vertical-align: top;*** to the `<td>` in cause.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top">
    Name
</td>
```